# How to make text in an element appear only when viewing a specific part of the page based on percentage not pixels?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

### Objective

In a header I want the text in my "tagline" to not be shown when landing on the page. But when you scroll to a certain point, it will then show.

### Background

When I looked up similar questions they suggest using javascript. And they are based on scrolling a certain number of pixels.

However my background on the first element has a cover width and height of 100% so i need to be able to display the text only when someone is on the second portion of the page.

### Code

Demo on [CodePen](http://codepen.io/JGallardo/pen/WrNbzO)

#### HTML

```
<header>
  Company

  <span class="tagline">
    We are the best
  </span>
</header>
```

Comment: You didn't post the JavaScript you tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initially, you want to set the `display` of your span to `none`.

Next, add an event listener for the `scroll` event, and keep track of the scroll position from the top. We can do this by using `document.body.scrollTop`.

If it's higher than a specified amount, we set the `display` attribute to `block`, and if it's lower, we set display to `hidden`.

```
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("tagLine")[0];
span.style.display = "none";

document.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 300) {
        span.style.display = "block";
    }
    else {
        span.style.display = "hidden";
    }
});
```

Here's a fiddle example

http://jsfiddle.net/8drp9o7n/2

Comment: So here after you scroll down 300px, then the span will show? This works, not as I anticipated, but I can work off of it and modify. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As far as i can understand you have a block with height 100% and you want to display something only when the block is scrolled out of the view.

This is how i would do that.

```
var elem = document.querySelector('.tagline');
elem.style.visibility = "hidden";

window.onscroll  = function( e ) {
    var scrollPercentage = window.scrollY / window.innerHeight;
    elem.style.visibility = (scrollPercentage>1) ? "visible" : "hidden";
};
```

Edited: i made some canges to the code,  here is the [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KVKpgx)

Comment: This looks right but getting an error in my demo. If you don't mind could you fork form my demo so I can see what you did?

Comment: On that codepen demo, the tagline shows by default, which it is not supposed to. Perhaps a small typo somewhere?

Comment: My bad. I was hiding the main div. I edited the code to work with the linetag.

Answer (score 1):

This could be overkill compared to some of the other answers, but this is a good option to have in your arsenal. There is a Javascript library called Waypoints that is excellent for handling this sort of thing.

http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/

Once you get the library installed onto your page and assuming you're using jQuery, and assuming your .tagline is hidden to start with, use this code (referencing your Codepen demo):

```
var waypoints = $('#main').waypoint({
    handler: function() {
        $('.tagline').show();
    }
});
```

The idea being, when the user scrolls to the Waypoint set up at #main, the handler will trigger. There are even options to do something different if the user is scrolling up or down, and to create offsets (so, trigger in the middle of a page, for example.)

This should get you to where you need to go.

Comment: This is a great suggestion. Not really in context but definitely helpful, thank you.